# Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort WMI query is empty

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi

When I query WMI (by any method so far) for printers:

```
select * from Win32_Printer
```

I get normal results.  When I try to query for ports:

```
select * from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort
```

the query "succeeds" but I get no results.  There are over 100 ports on this server, but neither prnport.vbs, wbemtest, powershell, or my own code are getting any results.

Operating system in **2003R2** and the user has admin privs.

Comment: Where question: is there a service that this relies on? What supplies the local port information? What answers the WMI query? Any of this could lead to the source of the issue! Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that local ports (and consequently redirected locals like ghostscript etc) are NOT listed by this WMI query.  They are stored directly in the registry.  This means that normal scripting to migrate these printer parameters will get the printers but not the port information.

They are stored in:
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Redirected Port\Ports`

Live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple print servers with many queues on them and they are running on MS Windows 2003.  I required the port configuration as well.  Namely queue and protocol.  I nested the following commands in my foreach loop and I was able to get the data I needed:

```
$PrintQueue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\$Queue" -Name Queue).Queue

$Protocol = (Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\$Queue" -Name Protocol).Protocol
```

$Queue variable in the path string above is the print queue variable in my foreach loop.  Change it to the Print Queue name as needed or set the variable earlier in the code.

I also ran into print queues that did not have a Queue value set so I added a if statement to set one, which I required in order to feed this data to another script that installs the print queue on a 2012R2 server.

```
if($PrintQueue = $null){
    $PrintQueue = 'Print'
    }#if
```

Hope this helps.